# Async SaveChanges In a transaction to run Validations in Parallel

Tags: validation, asynchronous

I'm looking for some guidance on an situation I've been contemplating.
I'm creating an Async Crud Operations, and using the time during communication to validate, and only commit the transaction if this is valid.

```
public async Task<SkillDTO> Update(int id, SkillDTO skillDTO)
{
    using (var transaction = this._context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var skill = await this._context.Skills.FindAsync(id);
        skillDTO.CopyTo(new SkillAdapter(skill));

        //Start SaveChanges Execution
        var saveChangesTask = this._context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //Use free time to validate
        var validator = new SkillValidator();
        //Note Validator Will throw if not valid
        validator.Validate(skill);

        await saveChangesTask;
        transaction.Commit();

        return new SkillAdapter(skill).ToDTO();
    }        
}
```

What the pro's and con's?
Is this a dangerous operation because you are executing code that is unneeded if failed validation?
 Or does this seem like a valid way to increase efficiency?

Comment: Unless you're doing some **excessively heavy algorithmic** validation, it would take **far** less time to run all the validations than to communicate with your DB server at all.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for your reply,  So basically I should never do this unless I have some intense Validations

Comment: Yes, I'd say that.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the answer,  I wasn't intending on using it in production,  I'm just glad it was a semi-valid idea